# In Hibernate is it possible (and how) to create an association to a named query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is about mapping computed columns cleanly into entities in Hibernate. I have a complex SQL query that creates a view that has computed columns. A simple version to illustrate is below where the avg function call would be a bunch of gritty SQL ...

```
CREATE VIEW `Complex` AS
select
    `p`.`parentId` AS `complexId`,
    avg(`t1`.`someColumn`) AS `complexColumn`
from
    (`Parent` `p`
    join `Table1` `t1` ON ((`p`.`parentId` = `t1`.`table1Id`)))
group by `p`.`parentId`
```

There is an entity class for Complex that is used in an association back to Parent joined by complexId:

```
 @Entity
 public class Parent {
 ...
 @OneToOne
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "complexId")
 private Complex complex;
...
```

Any collection queries that return Parent, nicely return the results of the associated view that has the computed columns.

The question here is if there is a way to create this same association by writing the complex query without the view, for example as a named hibernate query and keeping the association in Parent to Complex as it is?

The reason for this is due to the limitations of views in MySql regarding parameters and sub queries which could be avoided if this could all be represented in a non view oriented query.

Answer (score 0):

How complex is your SQL? Hibernate has @Formula which might be a possibility:

```
public class Parent{

@Formula("select avg(xyz) from some_table where parent_id = ?")
private BigDecimal average;


}
```

Hibernate also has support for Filters which are described as being:

> like database views, but they are parameterized inside the
>   application.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html

Comment: Problem with using Formula in my case is that there is more than one complex column and these also depend on other computed results, so using Formula's would have a lot of duplicated sub queries, which will end up running as separate queries instead of being optimized into one.